# Django override custom admin site's templates

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have two admin sites in my django app. One named `admin` and the other named `owneradmin`.
I want to override their templates separately. Is there a way to do it ?

Comment: What kind of operations you want to do by overriding it ? List more fields of a model,filtering,sorting?

Comment: I would like to override the `admin/index.html` and the `owneradmin/index.html` separately to add some custom plots. For now I only can change the `admin/index.html` and the changes are taken into accont in both admins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to override the index template, the easiest way is to set `index_template` for the `AdminSite`.

```
CustomAdminSite.index_template = 'path/to/custom/template.html'

OwnerAdminSite.index_template = 'path/to/owner/template.html'
```

See [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.index_template) for more details about index template and template overriding.